# How do I unserialize a java object on jython

Tags: java, python, serialization, jython

I have a java object which I retrieve using a HTTP request. How can I 'un-serialize' the java data in jython?

Comment: What is the serialization format? In any case you should be able to pull in the appropriate Java libraries and use them to deserialize your data.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to guess you are using ObjectOutputStream to serialize. In which case pull in ObjectInputStream in your jython program and use it to deserialize your object(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the project [python-javaobj](http://code.google.com/p/python-javaobj/) is what you are looking for.

Alternatively you could perhaps consider using another, simpler format for serializing objects like JSON... ?!

Comment: Thanks. My reason for specifically asking about jython was because I couldn't find a standard python module. This does exactly what I need.

Comment: @zio jython is a python implementation written entirely in Java, and one of the benefits is that you have access to all the java libraries in your python...you only have to write import 'java.io as io' and then 'myObjOutputStream = ObjectOutputStream(...)' Using a python library to do this when youre using jython is dumb. That would have been an acceptable answer if you were using python, but since you're using jython, you should not have listed this as the accepted answer. This isn't wrong perse, but its a horrible answer. Steven D. Majewski has the correct answer.

Comment: I just saw, his answer was also wrong. but its far closer to the right answer. It should be 'from org.python.util import PythonObjectInputStream'

Answer (score 2):

You just call the java methods to deserialize from Jython.

Looks like you have to create an ObjectInputStream from your InputStream and then call readObject on it. Something like:

```
import java.io
jobj = java.io.ObjectInputStream( httpinputstream ).readObject()
```

You already got an answer to this in [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8227332/decoding-java-objects-in-python).

If you want a more detailed answer, you need to provide details. 
Where is your HTTP request coming from ? an HttpURLConnection ?

Comment: Sort of, It should be 'import org.python.util.PythonObjectInputStream'